# Configuring multiple alternate authentication options with precedence in WebApi

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am unclear on how to achieve multiple alternate authentication options with precedence -

I can successfully separately implement

- OAuth (Single Sign On)
- API key Authentication (passed as a header)

What I am unclear on - how do I configure it so that if the API key header is present and the API key is valid to process the request; that is if you have a valid API-Key, you do not need the SSO.
If no API-Key is presented then you should expect to pass SSO.

The default should be SSO - hence I have the following configured in my `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services
        .AddAuthentication(
            options =>
            {
                // If an authentication cookie is present, use it to get authentication information
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                // If authentication is required, and no cookie is present, 
                // use OAuth to sign in
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OAuth";
            }
        )
        .AddCookie(
            options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/accessdenied";
            }
        )
        .AddOAuth(
            "OAuth",
            (OAuthOptions options) =>
            {
             // abstracted out but takes care of claims, etc...   
             WebApp.Utils.OAuthHelper.Process(options, OAuthConfig);
            }
        );
```

But my question is - how do I configure this to say - if API Key Header is present, don't bother with OAuth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`AuthenticationSchemeOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationschemeoptions?view=aspnetcore-6.0) class has [`ForwardDefaultSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationschemeoptions.forwarddefaultselector?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that allows any [`AuthenticationHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhandler-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to forward authentication events to another handler.

So what you can do is make your `ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler` the detault and make it forward authentication events to OAuth handler if API Key header is not present in the HTTP headers.

For example: Let's say you implement ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler as Follows:

```cs
// API Key options
public class ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public string ApiKeyHeaderName { get; set; } = "X-MY-API-KEY";

    // Add more options here if needed
}

// API Key Authentication handler
public class ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions>
{
    // Inject any additional services needed by your key handler here
    public ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // Validation logic here
        // Check if the header exists
        if (!Context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(Options.ApiKeyHeaderName, out var headerValues))
        {
            // Header is not present fail
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid API key.");
        }

        // Header is present validate user
        var user = await GetApiKeyUserAsync(headerValues.First());
        if (user == null)
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid API key.");
        }

        // API Key is valid, generate a ClaimIdentity and Principal for the authenticated user
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user)
        }, Scheme.Name);

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        return AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(principal, null, Scheme.Name));
    }

    // Key validation logic here and you can map an API key to a user
    private async Task<string?> GetApiKeyUserAsync(string key)
    {
        // Add your implementation here
        if (key == "Alice's Key")
        {
            return "Alice";
        }

        if (key == "Bob's Key")
        {
            return "Bob";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now in the startup class call `AddAuthentication` and make `"ApiKey"` the default, and add a Selector function that checks the HTTP Headers for the presence of a key, if the key is present, then return `null` and let the  Api key handler handle the authentication, otherwiser forward to "OAuth".

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(
        options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
                "ApiKey";
        }
    )
    .AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>("ApiKey", apiKeyOptions =>
    {
        // This scheme will forward Authentication to OAUTH if API Key header is not present
        apiKeyOptions.ForwardDefaultSelector = (context) =>
        {
            // Check the HTTP Request for the presence of Header
            if (!context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(apiKeyOptions.ApiKeyHeaderName, out var headerValues))
            {
                // Header is not present, forward to OAuth
                return "OAuth"; // "OAuth" is the scheme name you specified when you called "AddOAuth()
            }

            // Do not forward the authentication
            return null;
        };
    })
    // Add other schemes here
```